# Do NS records have point to name servers with matching SOA?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, ns-record

I have a requirement to delegate many but not all domains to another DNS server.

To simplify things, I'd like to delegate all of them to the same DNS server/zone, rather than one for each. Is that possible?

Can I delegate to one server with the same SOA as the original?

**44.44.44.44 (original)**

```
example.com SOA example.com 
example.com NS 44.44.44.44
...other records...
a.example.com NS 55.55.55.55
b.example.com NS 55.55.55.55
c.example.com NS 55.55.55.55
d.example.com NS 55.55.55.55
```

**55.55.55.55**

```
example.com SOA example.com
example.com NS 55.55.55.55
a.example.com A 66.0.0.1
b.example.com A 66.0.0.2
c.example.com A 66.0.0.3
d.example.com A 66.0.0.4
```

Comment: I'm having issues understanding the question. It sounds like you have multiple domains (ie domain1.com, domain2.com, domainN.com) and you want to point to a single name server, and to save duplication of work, the same zone file? What name server are you using? If my understanding is correct, I'm assuming you have no differences in the zones other than the domain name itself?

Comment: Target of NS records are names, not IP addresses...